# changing null hypothesis value for sample size calculation of a single AUC

Tags: r, roc, auc, sample-size

I am trying to get the sample size for a single AUC using power.roc.test in the pROC package. For example, the expected AUC is 0.97 (alternative hypothesis) and the value I am comparing to is 0.95 (null hypothesis). At the significance level of 0.05 and power of 0.80, I get 433 positives and 433 negatives using MedCalc, a statistical software. However, I want to carry this out in R. I cannot find any package that allows me to set the null hypothesis value.

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

In pROC, I can use power.roc.test but there is no argument to set the null hypothesis value; it defaults to 0.50.

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the binary predictor does random guesses resulting always in an AUC of 0.5

Comment: @danlooo yes, I said that above, "it defaults to 0.50." But I want to change it, for example, to 0.95.

Comment: I think it defaults to 0.5 not "by default" but "by definition".

Comment: @Calimo can I take that answer as that there is no way to test against other values in R?

Comment: @Calimo, I don't think it necessarily so by definition. For example if your alternative hypothesis was that a certain test would out perform another.

Comment: @slee not that I know of at least.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same question. It is possible to compute a sample size using with two `roc` objects with `power.roc.test()`, e.g.

```
power.roc.test(roc1, roc2, power = 0.8)
```

although I want to compute a sample size just for two different AUC values (one representing the null hypothesis, like MedCalc).

Answer (score 0):

I could also not find a solution in R.
But if this helps, I found out that in MedCalc software you can define the null hypothesis value, e.g., as = 0.95.
This is displayed e.g., here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6683590/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33555576)